# IE9 javascript replace does not work

Tags: javascript, replace, internet-explorer-9

I have a string such as "Value = $val$" and I want to replace $val$ with some value like "$0.00"

so final string can look like "Value = $0.00"

This works in firefox and IE 7 and IE 8 but does not work in IE 9 any idea why? and how I can resolve the issue?

Any value other than $0.00 (e.g.$5.00) works without any issue.

<strike>http://jsfiddle.net/jhdVV/5/</strike>

edit: updated link with a textbox and a button to test with diff values.

http://jsfiddle.net/jhdVV/10/

In IE 9 I am getting "Value =$val$.00"

Browser is in Standards mode.

Note:
I am working on legacy code so , ideally I would like to stay away from tempting jquery solutions.

Comment: I don't know the solution, but the problem is that $0 is regex-speak.

Comment: @Boo thanks for pointing out $0. I tried with $<space>0.00 and IE9 replaces it properly. But I am escaping $ with \\$ first. Seems like an IE9 bug?? :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$0` in your replacement text is essentially an uninitialized variable, the behavior of which is undefined. So, escape the dollar sign:

```
$$0.00
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. adding extra $ sign did the trick.

Answer (score 5):

Any reason you're not simply doing this?

```
function replaceValue(source, find, replacement) {
    return source.replace(find, replacement);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the enlightenment. For some reason , I believed that I need to escape those special characters.I tried your code and it works. I will wait if someone answers why my code behaves strangely with IE9 for a day and will mark your answer if I do not get any satisfactory answers regarding that. Meanwhile , +1 for you..